# Trouble bordering images in css

Tags: css, html

This is my first post, and I apologize- pretty much a newbie. I have tried every technique that I can think of, and cant figure out how to create borders around three specific pictures in my site. My site is [glh222.github.io](http://glh222.github.io/)

You will notice 6 images, three of which are bordered and sized appropriately and the other 3 which are enormously big. I have edited all pictures to be 285px, and my code in the HTML and CSS is consistent. I will post the code to both the relevant sections of the html and css below, please let me know if anyone can help. Thanks in advance!

```
<section id="GT">
<a href="#">
<img src="Images/gtsport.jpg" alt="Granturismo on an open road">
<p>Granturismo</p>
</a>
</section>
<section id="GTC">
<a href="#">
<img src="Images/GTC.jpg" alt="Granturismo Convertible">
<p>Granturismo Convertible</p>
</a>
</section>
<section id="GHIBLI">
<a href="#">    
<img src="Images/GhibliSnow.jpg" alt="Ghibli in the snow">
<p>Ghibli</p>
</a>
</section>
<section id="GHIBLISQ4"
<a href="#">
<img src="Images/GTSLogo1.jpg" alt="SQ4 Logo">
<p>Ghibli SQ4</p>
</a>
</section>
<section id="QP"
<a href="#">
<img src="Images/QPblur1.jpg" alt="QP blurred">
<p>Quattroporte</p>
</a>
</section>
<section id="QPS"
<a href="#">
<img src="Images/GTSrear1.jpg" alt="Rear Facing in the snow">
<p>Quattroporte GTS</p>
</a>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#GT img {
width:100%;
padding:.5em, auto;
margin: .5em;
background-color:#c7ccf;
border: 20px black solid;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
float: left;
}

#GTC
img {
width:100%;
padding:.5em, auto;
margin: .5em;
background-color:#c7ccf;
border: 20px black solid;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

#GHIBLI
img {
width:100%;
padding:.5em, auto;
margin: .5em;
background-color:#c7ccf;
border: 20px black solid;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

#GHIBLISQ4
img {
width:100%;
padding:.5em, auto;
margin: .5em;
background-color:#c7ccf;
border: 20px black solid;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

#QP
img {
width:100%;
padding:.5em, auto;
margin: .5em;
background-color:#c7ccf;
border: 20px black solid;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

#QPS
img {
width:100%;
padding:.5em, auto;
margin: .5em;
background-color:#c7ccf;
border: 20px black solid;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 800;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
}

a:hover {
background-color: #aaaaaa;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't getting the borders on the bottom 3 because your code is broken in multiple areas.

First, you have an extra:

```
<link href=
```

near the top of your page and
you are missing a > at the end of these three lines:

```
   <section id="GHIBLISQ4"
```

should be:

```
   <section id="GHIBLISQ4">
```

same goes for:

```
    <section id="QP"
```

should be:

```
    <section id="QP">
```

and

```
<section id="QPS"
```

should be:

```
    <section id="QPS">
```

Your full code should look like this:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
                    <title>"Maserati of Long Island"</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <header>
                            <h1> Welcome to Maserati of Long Island, A Division of The Experience Auto Group
                            Maserati...The Absolute Opposite of Ordinary</h1>
                    </header>
                        <div id="slogan">
                            <h2>Long Island's only factory authorized dealership</h2>
                        </div>
                    <section id="GT">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="Images/gtsport.jpg" alt="Granturismo on an open road">
                                <p>Granturismo</p>
                            </a>
                    </section>
                    <section id="GTC">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="Images/GTC.jpg" alt="Granturismo Convertible">
                                <p>Granturismo Convertible</p>
                            </a>
                    </section>
                    <section id="GHIBLI">
                            <a href="#">    
                                <img src="Images/GhibliSnow.jpg" alt="Ghibli in the snow">
                                <p>Ghibli</p>
                            </a>
                    </section>
                    <section id="GHIBLISQ4">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="Images/GTSLogo1.jpg" alt="SQ4 Logo">
                                <p>Ghibli SQ4</p>
                            </a>
                    </section>
                    <section id="QP">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="Images/QPblur1.jpg" alt="QP blurred">
                                <p>Quattroporte</p>
                            </a>
                    </section>
                    <section id="QPS">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="Images/GTSrear1.jpg" alt="Rear Facing in the snow">
                                <p>Quattroporte GTS</p>
                            </a>
                    </section>
                        </nav>
                    <section id="about">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <h2>Operating from a state-of-the-art facility that's located in the heart of Long Island, our expertly trained staff is committed to serving each of your needs from the moment you walk through our doors, keeping one tenet in mind above all else: treating you like a member of our "family" from the moment you walk through the doors</h2> 
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <footer>
                        <p> You can contact us by calling (516) 665-1665, or if you prefer, you can stop by  65 South Service Rd, Plainview, New York 11803 and speak with us in person.</p>
                    </footer>
                </body>
            </html>
```

This will make your page look like the following:
[image]

Additionally, you may want to one single CSS class for your images, and then apply that class to all images instead of using separate classes for each image. This way, all your photos will be uniform and styled identically, and you won't have to write as much code.

You may also want to resize/crop your photos as well, as they are uneven right now, partially due to the fact that while they are all the same width, they are not all the same height, so some are taller than others.

AND

if you want to get rid of that gray box around your first image, remove the **float:left;** on the #GT img CSS

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you helping me out

Answer (score 0):

- Your HTML was broken. Some of your `section` tags weren't closed with a `>`.
- If you want to apply same rules to several elements, give them a `class`. I gave the elements class of `.cars` in my fix below.
- You shouldn't be applying text formatting rules to an `img` tag, but instead the elements that actually contain some text.
- You might want to use `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:top;` instead of `float:left;` because your elements have different heights.
- Remove `width:100%` from your image if you want it to retain its original size. If you want each of the elements to have the same width, apply a width to the container (the `section` element) and and give the `img` a `max-width` of `100%`.

```css
.cars{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.cars a{
    display:block;
    padding: .5em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.cars p{
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.cars img {
    background-color:#c7ccf;
    border: 20px black solid;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* so the sizing of the image will include its border */
}
.cars a:hover {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<section id="GT" class="cars">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://glh222.github.io/Images/gtsport.jpg" alt="Granturismo on an open road">
        <p>Granturismo</p>
    </a>
</section>
<section id="GTC" class="cars">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://glh222.github.io/Images/GTC.jpg" alt="Granturismo Convertible">
        <p>Granturismo Convertible</p>
    </a>
</section>
<section id="GHIBLI" class="cars">
    <a href="#"> 
        <img src="http://glh222.github.io/Images/GhibliSnow.jpg" alt="Ghibli in the snow">
        <p>Ghibli</p>
    </a>
</section>
<section id="GHIBLISQ4" class="cars">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://glh222.github.io/Images/GTSLogo1.jpg" alt="SQ4 Logo">
        <p>Ghibli SQ4</p>
    </a>
</section>
<section id="QP" class="cars"> 
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://glh222.github.io/Images/QPblur1.jpg" alt="QP blurred">
        <p>Quattroporte</p>
    </a>
</section>
<section id="QPS" class="cars">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://glh222.github.io/Images/GTSrear1.jpg" alt="Rear Facing in the snow">
        <p>Quattroporte GTS</p>
    </a>
</section>
```